# how to detect number of days of the succeeding month in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker, vb.net-2010

I have two datetimepickers and one textbox. One is for effectivitydate and the other one is for expirationdate. Textbox is for the result number of days of two datetimepickers. If the textbox is 5 days beyond the succeeding month then the messagebox will popup with the message "The document was submitted beyond 5 days of the succeeding month!"

Comment: Show us what you've tried so we can better understand what you are doing.

Comment: .. also kindly include where will be the succeeding month is based.

Comment: @CrushSundae This is the code that I've tried ` Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim expireffectdiff As Long = DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, DateTimePicker2.Value, DateTimePicker1.Value)
        Label1.Text = expireffectdiff
        If Label1.Text > 4 Then
            MsgBox("The document was submitted beyond 5 days of the succeeding month from the date of effectivity!")
        End If

    End Sub`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

`Dim maxDate = New Date(Now.Year, Now.Month + 1, 5)`